# How to take jSON string through ajax and convert in php array?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am new to ajax and json.

I have two files name script.js and submitComprehension.php here.

In script.js, I have a funciton named submit(). Here,objQuestion has already values and is converted into json string succesfully.
Code:

```
function submit(){
    var str_objQuestion=JSON.stringify(objQuestion);
    $.ajax({
    data:"objQuestion="+str_objQuestion,
    url:"submitComprehension.php",
    success:function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
})
```

}

Here is the json value after converting into string.

```
[{"qid":820,"question":"Comprehension-1/Question-4","opt_a":"Comprehension-1/Question-4/Option-A","opt_b":"Comprehension-1/Question-4/Option-B","opt_c":"Comprehension-1/Question-4/Option-C","opt_d":"Comprehension-1/Question-4/Option-D","user_ans":"a","cor_ans":"D"},{"qid":822,"question":"Comprehension-1/Question-6","opt_a":"Comprehension-1/Question-6/Option-A","opt_b":"Comprehension-1/Question-6/Option-B","opt_c":"Comprehension-1/Question-6/Option-C","opt_d":"Comprehension-1/Question-6/Option-D","user_ans":"b","cor_ans":"C"},{"qid":819,"question":"Comprehension-1/Question-3","opt_a":"Comprehension-1/Question-3/Option-A","opt_b":"Comprehension-1/Question-3/Option-B","opt_c":"Comprehension-1/Question-3/Option-C","opt_d":"Comprehension-1/Question-3/Option-D","user_ans":"c","cor_ans":"C"},{"qid":823,"question":"Comprehension-1/Question-7","opt_a":"Comprehension-1/Question-7/Option-A","opt_b":"Comprehension-1/Question-7/Option-B","opt_c":"Comprehension-1/Question-7/Option-C","opt_d":"Comprehension-1/Question-7/Option-D","user_ans":"d","cor_ans":"D"},{"qid":826,"question":"Comprehension-1/Question-10","opt_a":"Comprehension-1/Question-10/Option-A","opt_b":"Comprehension-1/Question-10/Option-B","opt_c":"Comprehension-1/Question-10/Option-C","opt_d":"Comprehension-1/Question-10/Option-D","user_ans":"a","cor_ans":"C"},{"qid":821,"question":"Comprehension-1/Question-5","opt_a":"Comprehension-1/Question-5/Option-A","opt_b":"Comprehension-1/Question-5/Option-B","opt_c":"Comprehension-1/Question-5/Option-C","opt_d":"Comprehension-1/Question-5/Option-D","user_ans":"d","cor_ans":"A"},{"qid":824,"question":"Comprehension-1/Question-8","opt_a":"Comprehension-1/Question-8/Option-A","opt_b":"Comprehension-1/Question-8/Option-B","opt_c":"Comprehension-1/Question-8/Option-C","opt_d":"Comprehension-1/Question-8/Option-D","user_ans":"d","cor_ans":"A"},{"qid":825,"question":"Comprehension-1/Question-9","opt_a":"Comprehension-1/Question-9/Option-A","opt_b":"Comprehension-1/Question-9/Option-B","opt_c":"Comprehension-1/Question-9/Option-C","opt_d":"Comprehension-1/Question-9/Option-D","user_ans":"c","cor_ans":"B"},{"qid":817,"question":"Comprehension-1/Question-1","opt_a":"Comprehension-1/Question-1/Option-A","opt_b":"Comprehension-1/Question-1/Option-B","opt_c":"Comprehension-1/Question-1/Option-C","opt_d":"Comprehension-1/Question-1/Option-D","user_ans":"b","cor_ans":"A"},{"qid":818,"question":"Comprehension-1/Question-2","opt_a":"Comprehension-1/Question-2/Option-A","opt_b":"Comprehension-1/Question-2/Option-B","opt_c":"Comprehension-1/Question-2/Option-C","opt_d":"Comprehension-1/Question-2/Option-D","user_ans":"a","cor_ans":"B"}]
```

In submitComprehension.php, here is a code:

```
<?php include_once("../connection.php"); ?>
<?php
$objQuestion=json_decode($_REQUEST['objQuestion']);
$question=array();
$question=$objQuestion;
print_r($question);?>
```

But when I run submitComprehension.php, it gives error about undefined index:objQuestion

Please help me out here.

Answer (score 3):

Change
`data:"objQuestion="+str_objQuestion,`
to

```
 data:{"objQuestion:"+str_objQuestion},
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your submit function as given below :

```
function submit(){
    var str_objQuestion=JSON.stringify(objQuestion);
    $.ajax({
    data:{objQuestion : str_objQuestion},
    url:"submitComprehension.php",
    success:function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
})
```